# can we test the in-app purchase android application via GOOGLE APIs emulator

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have one question in my mind that can we test the in-app purchase application in Google Apis emulator with different api level?

Any information regarding this will be welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot test services like in app billing and LVL on emulators as they lack Google Play, which acts as a middleman between your app and then launch Google servers. Additionally, the accounts you can configure on the emulator are limited in functionality.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) for details on testing.

Comment: thanks for your time and information. also one thing i want to ask you is that the link you have mentioned in that, one example is there to explain those things so from where i can get that example with code?

Comment: The example is Downloaded to your machine when you use the sdk manager to download the in app billing component.

Comment: That depends on where you installed the sdk, so I can't.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. There's a way to test you in-app billing, but it's something you have to install on a real device, not the emulator:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

"To test in-app billing in an application you must install the application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use the Android emulator to test in-app billing."

Comment: ok thanks for the information you have mentioned. Now where can I download the android in-app purchase example that android developer site is talking about in the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) ?

Comment: Well, I'm only gonna guess here, as I never did this, but if you get the latest Android SDK you should find it among the samples that come with it.

Answer (score 1):

I know of this open-source library project called [android-test-billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing/) who apparently lets you test IAB in the emulator by recreating the Google Play Billing Service.

I haven't tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can test. Login into Google play with google account. Now purchase the in-app products.

Comment: The purchase made in an emulator device will be a Sandbox Purchase or it will be a real purchase . Can you please confirm?